# Paginate parse queries using a regular UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, parse-platform

I have a `UIViewController` with a tableview in it. I populate the tableview using the regular methods. I call my query using a method called `loadEntries`.

The problem is that the amount of entries the `loadEntries` can be more then tens of thousands.

I would rather not change my ViewController to a PFQueryTableViewController, exception can be made if there is a sneaky way to change from UIViewcontroller to PFQueryTableViewController.

so my questions is: Is it possible to implement pagination with parse.com queries(Not using PFQueryTableViewController), if yes, how?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to take a look at the `skip` parameter of `PFQuery` as discussed [here in Parse's PFQuery Documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/skip).

You can run the query the first time as just a count, and then you will be able to determine how many pages of data you'll have.

Then, you can run the query with `skip` and 'count' values based on the "page" the user is currently viewing.

Something like this:

```
- (void)countRecords {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"className"];
    // Other query parameters assigned here...
    [query countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int count, NSError *error) {
        // Do better error handling in your app...
        self.recordCount = count;
        self.pageCount   = count / self.recordsPerPage + 1;
        [self loadRecordsForPageIndex:0 countPerPage:self.recordsPerPage];
    }];
}
- (void)loadRecordsForPageIndex:(NSInteger)pageIndex countPerPage:(NSInteger)count {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"className"];
    // Other query parameters assigned here...
    query.limit    = count;
    query.skip     = pageIndex * count;
    [query findObjects... // You should know this part
}
```

In the above example, `-countRecords` gets the current count of the records matching your query and then automatically calls `-loadRecordsForPageIndex:countPerPage:`. Later, when the user navigates between pages of data, you would call this again, passing in the new `pageIndex` and `count` (records per page) values. You could refactor this to keep referencing `self.recordsPerPage` as the instance variable it is or not.

From Parse.com directly:

> Caveat: Count queries are rate limited to a maximum of 160 requests per minute. They can also return inaccurate results for classes with more than 1,000 objects. Thus, it is preferable to architect your application to avoid this sort of count operation (by using counters, for example.)

***MY CAVEATS:***

1. The default value for `limit` is 100.
2. The maximum allowed value for `limit` is 1,000.
3. The default value for `skip` is 0 (zero).
4. The maximum allowed value for `skip` is 10,000.
5. Therefore, you cannot reliably query more than 11,000 objects with one single, unmodified query. (You can get advanced and search using `createdAt` or something, but those would be `PFQuery` instances with different constraints.)

Comment: Thanks for answering!
The `query.skip` will always be `0`. Since the `pageIndex` is 0. The `query.skip` should have the same value as the amount of loaded objects, am i right?

Comment: I got it to work! I did some minor changes and now it works like a charm! thanks a lot @mbm29414

Comment: I was assuming you would update pageIndex as the user pages through the data.

Comment: I set the `loadRecordsForPageIndex` to equal the amount of entries in my array i use to store my data. Thanks a lot once again!